# PayPal returns ACK Failure on SetExpressCheckout

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I try to get the token for the PayPal by providing the following data in PayPal:

```
Array
(
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE] => EUR
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM] => TLT-GR-1
    [RETURNURL] => http://www.mysite.ext/my_app/payment-completed/
    [CANCELURL] => http://www.mysite.ext/my_app/payment-canceled/
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
    [SOLUTIONTYPE] => Sole
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0] => Product Description
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0] => 0.38
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0] => 19.27
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 7.32
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT] => 1
)
```

This is the code that generating the above array values:

```
$data           =   array();

$data['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE']  =   $currencyCode;
$data['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM']        =   $order->ID;
$data['RETURNURL']                      =   $returnUrl;
$data['CANCELURL']                      =   $cancelUrl;
$data['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION'] =   'Sale';
$data['SOLUTIONTYPE']                   =   'Sole';

$subtotal   =   0;
$tax        =   0;
$counter    =   0;

foreach($products as $product)
{
    if($product->Type == 0)     //  Production is diretion
    {
        if($product->NightDuration == 0)
        {
            $price  =   round($product->Price   ,   2);
            $qty    =   round($product->Qty     ,   2);

            $data['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME'         .   $counter]   =   $product->Title;
            $data['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'          .   $counter]   =   $price;
            $data['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER'       .   $counter]   =   ($counter + 1);
            $data['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY'          .   $counter]   =   $qty;
            $data['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT'       .   $counter]   =   round(($qty * $price) * ($taxPercentage / 100), 2);
            $data['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY' .   $counter]   =   'Digital';
            $subtotal                                               +=  $qty * $price;
            $tax                                                    +=  ($qty * $price) * ($taxPercentage / 100);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    else
    {

    }

    $counter++;
}

$data['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT']           =   round($subtotal + $tax, 2);
$data['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT']       =   1;
$data['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT']        =   round($tax, 2);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
$data                                   =   http_build_query($data, '', '&');

$pp =   new TaxiBookingPayPal();
$rt =   $pp->PPHttpPost('SetExpressCheckout', $data);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($rt);
echo "</pre>";
```

and I get the following result from PayPal:

```
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2013%2d01%2d19T14%3a44%3a25Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => bdfce7f34a1db
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 94
    [BUILD] => 4181146
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10413
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Transaction%20refused%20because%20of%20an%20invalid%20argument%2e%20See%20additional%20error%20messages%20for%20details%2e
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => The%20totals%20of%20the%20cart%20item%20amounts%20do%20not%20match%20order%20amounts%2e
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
```

Can you see anything wrong in that code ? Is there anybody who can help me ?

After a long time research in my code, I have see that the issue comes from the decimal digits in my numbers. The issue is that I don't know what exactly is the wrong with the decimals :(

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ITEMAMT + TAXAMT + SHIPPINGAMT + HANDLINGAMT must equal AMT.

ITEMAMT should be the subtotal of just the items, but you're only passing a 1 there.

Also, you have a QTY of 19.27.  I've never tested specifically to see if they'll accept QTY values like that, but even if they do, your ITEMAMT should be 7.32.

In this case, you're not passing the other values, so your ITEMAMT and AMT would be the same.  That 1 you're passing there is causing the error you're getting because it doesn't add up to your AMT.

Comment: I already have change my code with correction and now working. THe issue is with quantities. In my case, because I cannot use decimals in L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0, I have calculate the final price, then I set it as AMT for the item and the QTY to 1, but still, as you can see this is a wrong approach.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the error message: The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.

The numbers you send to PayPal are incorrect. (are you sure your calculations are correct?)

Comment: I have try that calculations manualy and are correct, why not automaticly ?

Comment: I just updated my question by placing the PHP code that generating the data to see what is my code

Answer (score 1):

check whether any amount value does not have more than two decimal for example "12.123" not valid amount whereas "12.12" is valid amount.

while preparing the cart than total amount of the cart+extras(tax+shipping) must be equal to total amount

Comment: You are right. In my case, I have some values with four digits, but before use that values I round them up with two decimal digits length.